# Can the Entry URL Format of a Channel intersect with the Entry URL Format of a Structure?

Tags: url

Can the Entry URL Format of a Channel intersect with the Entry URL Format of a Structure? For example I have a Structure like this-

Top-Level Entries: products/{slug}

Nested Entries: {parent.uri}/{slug}

Can a Channel Entry URL Format be set so that the scenario below is possible?

1. products/shirts/reviews <-- review list page
2. products/shirts/reviews/{slug} <-- individual review

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where the review list page is in the structure? Yes. This works just the way you would expect. Set the review channel url to `products/shirts/reviews/{slug}` and it will do just that.